# Send Geometry Data to Multiple Shaders

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, deferred-rendering, vao

So I am implementing a deferred rending model for my engine, and I want to be able to send all scene geometry into a single shader to calculate ambient, diffuse, normal, ect thats not the question.

Once I have all of this data buffered into the GPU I can render all of that geometry from a camera perspective defined by a uniform for the cameras position in the scene. I am wondering if I can reuse this model data already in VRam in another shader translated by a light sources projection matrix to calculate the shadows on this scene geometry without needing to send the same data to the GPU again.

Is there a way to tell my light shader, hey all that juicy geometry/scene data you want is already in V-Ram, just use this matrix transformation instead.

Alternatively when I am sending the VAO to the GPU is there a way to send it to two shades in parallel, one for the deferred rending model, one for shadow casing light sources?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Generally you have two steps: 1) upload a buffer of geometry information to the GPU, 2) invoke a particular shader program using that geometry information. These are wholly separate operations. Step 2 doesn't delete the step 1 data from the GPU and force you to re-upload it again. It's still there. You can just do step 2 again with the same geometry buffer and a different shader program. Where have you run into difficulty implementing this?

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize the buffers were not flushed when using a different shading program. So i should just be able to use shader A, buffer my VAO into V-Ram do shader A's drawArraysInstanced then use shader B for lights, and the data will still be there. Cool Cool, did not realize this!

Comment: Always test and profile to see if it's behaving as you want. If it's not, post here with a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example showing how you've implemented the feature and how the results differ from what you want/expect.

Comment: This was more of an approach question, I haven't tried to implement this yet, I wanted to know if there was a way to send data in parallel to multiple shaders. It was probing for information on how to implement this concept to help me better decide how to do what I want to do.